# How to replace letters with lines? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I'm trying to build a hangman game and I need to "censor" the random word with lines, so that for example the word "ruby" is shown as four lines: _ _ _ _

The problem is that my method replaces the word with *two extra lines*.

Here is my method:

```
class Game
    attr_reader :the_word

    def initialize
        @the_word = random_word
        @player_input = Array.new
        @attempts_left = 10
    end

    def random_word
        @the_word = File.readlines("../5desk.txt").sample
    end

    def hide_the_word
        @hidden_word = @the_word.split("")
        @hidden_word.each {|letter| letter.replace("_")}
        puts "Can you guess what this word is? #{@hidden_word.join()}"
        puts @the_word #delete this
    end
end
```

If the random word is "ruby" I would like the game to replace the word with four lines, but it always shows two extra lines (with every random word).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. Post a [mcve] that, when run, will show the exact failing output. In other words, load in the text file for us or hardcode a word, remove the class. Chances are, you're not stripping a space or newline from the line, which would be revealed by `p @hidden_word`. Thanks. PS: `"_" * word.size` is likely a better way to do it.

Comment: For the purpose of the question, I suggest you replace `@the_word = File.readlines("../5desk.txt").sample` with something like `@the_word = ['they', 'were', 'ruby'].sample`, so that readers can run your code and show how it can be corrected and possibly improved. (Note `@the_word.split("")` is generally written `@the_word.chars`.)

Comment: The word is `underscore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your word from a file may contain spaces. You can remove them by using strip() method.

```
@the_word = File.readlines("../5desk.txt").sample.strip()
```

But, as @ggorien mentioned, a simpler way to achieve this is:

```
@hidden_word = "_" * @the_word.size
```

and change the puts to

```
puts "Can you guess what this word is? #{@hidden_word}"
```